# Communicate between Add-on SDK main add-on script and sdk/page-worker script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to communicate between my main Add-on SDK script, *index.js*, and a script in a page-worker created with `sdk/page-worker`. Unfortunately, I am having problems.

I am able to communicate from my main script to the page-worker: In the code below, I get an event from `socket.on` - `console.log('new post')` fires from the script in the page-worker.  However, the main add-on script does not see the message that is sent from the page-worker.

HTML (*worker.html*):

```html
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.21:8081');
            socket.on('newPost', function(data) {
                console.log("new post");
                //to this everything works ok!!!!!!!!!!!!
                self.port.emit('newPost', "");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

to *index.js* file:

```js
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var functions = require('./module.js');
var pageWorkers = require("sdk/page-worker");
var notifications = require('sdk/notifications');
var self = require("sdk/self");
functions.act.checkMsgsCount();

var pageWorker = pageWorkers.Page({
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentURL: self.data.url("worker.html")
});

pageWorker.port.on('newPost', function(data) {
    console.log("sent newPost");
    functions.act.newPostNotify();
});

buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "main-bt",
    label: "Start",
    icon: {
        "16" : "./icon-16.png",
        "32" : "./icon-32.png",
        "64" : "./icon-64.png"
    },    
    onClick: functions.act.checkMsgsCount
});
```

Comment: Maybe your message is sent before you listen for it?

Comment: @Aurélien how can I change it to listen after message is sent?

Comment: Maybe by delaying a bit your inline script execution ("on ready")... But before doing this, could you test a console log after your pageWorker.port.on, in order to see if it is fired before "new post" log?

Comment: @Aurélien but I've tried send this message many times and nothing

Comment: Any error/warning in the browser console window (in the `Tools>Web development` menu) related to your inline script?

Comment: @Aurélien oh :) yes there is error: self.port is undefined in worker.html line 18 - self.port.emit ...;

ok i have to change self to emit. Thank you ;)

Comment: Good. Feel free to +1 my comment then ;)

Answer (score 2):

In *worker.html*, I had to change `self.port.emit` to: `addon.port.emit`.

Because I used a script in my HTML file within a `<script>` tag, I have to communicate with the main add-on script through the `addon` object.

- ["Scripting Trusted Panel Content" in `sdk/page-worker`- from Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#Scripting_trusted_page_content)
- ["Scripting Trusted Panel Content" in `sdk/panel`- from Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting%20Trusted%20Panel%20Content)

Comment: Given that this is how you solved your problem, please accept your answer.